# Calculate sum of 2 columns in react , html table

Tags: html, reactjs

I am trying to find sum of 2 columns in html table in my react code.

```
const Fruits = () => (

  <table>

    <tr>
      <th>FRUIT NAME</th>
      <th>SOLD</th>
      <th>SCRAPPED</th>
    </tr>
    {Data.accounts.map((obj) => (
      <tr key={`${obj.label}-${Math.random()}`}>
        <td>{obj.name}</td>
        <td>{obj.sold}</td>
        <td>{obj.scrapped}</td>
      </tr>
    )
    )}
   
    <tr>
      <th>Total Amount</th>
      <th colSpan="2">Sum</th>
    </tr>

  </table>



   );
```

I am not sure what should be displayed in 'sum'.

Table looks like this
FRUITNAME             SOLD   SCARPPED
Mango                  5     2
Apple                  6     1
Total Amount           14

Comment: @devpolo can u help

Comment: @aschipfl can u help, just saw you helped me previously with a query.